# jQuery UI dialog: clicking on the title bar (including close button) makes the whole dialog scroll up

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Everytime I click on the jQuery UI dialog title bar, or the close button, the whole dialog first scrolls up to the top of the screen without triggering any ui events. Then I have to click a second time in order for the close event to be triggered.

Here is my code:

```
var dialog = $(selector).dialog(

    {
        autoOpen : true,
        modal : true,
        title : title,
        overlay : {
            opacity : "0.1",
            background : "black"
        },
        width : dWidth,
        height : dHeight,
        autoResize: false,
        resizable : true,
        effect: 'fade',
        zIndex: 100,
        close: function(ev, ui) {
            if(callback){
                callback();
            }
        }
```

I have tried to remove all the properties but I still get the bug. I am on jQuery UI 1.8.23, but the same bug appears on 1.9.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that you have some problems in close: option. Try to remove it or edit it and see what's going on.

Comment: In fact the close event is never reached. I've tried removing it but the same problem occurs. I always need to click twice and the second time the close event is triggered. It seems like the first click is just discarded somehow.

Comment: JSFiddle says it, this is not a core jQuery UI bug. However I am wondering now why in the world I am getting this double-click problem while clicking the ui dialog title bar only.

Comment: Btw, bug occurs on IE (tested on IE8 and IE9) only, not Firefox nor Chrome.

Comment: it's actually 500 and 800 respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try to put width : dWidth + 'px',

Also try to remove semi colon on callback.

```
close: function(ev, ui) {
        if(callback){
            callback()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with syntax as I tried it out without the entire close function but still the same bug appears. Something may be wrong with the CSS conflicting with ui-dialog css definition or so. But one thing for sure, IE, only...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3623
Upgrade your jqueryui

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me in IE, it was not just when clicking buttons but any click after scroll down. Solution was updating jQuery UI http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js